# Getting original class from casted class

Tags: c#

For example, I have three classes: `Animal`, `Dog` and `Cat`; where `Animal` is an abstract class and inherits its properties to `Dog` and `Cat`. Say on my program, I have an arbitrary list of things that the user may input (I'm doing this on C# Form). So I store all the inputs, whether they are of class `Cat` or `Dog`, into my `List<Animal>`.

Now I would like to retrieve said instantiated class from `List<Animal>` and retrieve its original class, whether it's a `Cat` or a `Dog`. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Retrieve and do what with it? please be more specific

Comment: Well you can find the type using GetType() but you shouldn't need to. See "Liskov Substitution Principle" https://stackoverflow.com/a/56904/224370

Comment: @TheGeneral I want to access the methods available in `Cat` and `Dog` that aren't available in `Animal`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In latest C# you can do:

```
Animal animal;
if (animal is Cat cat)
{
   cat.Meow();
}
```

Comment: Is there a name for this syntax?

Comment: @RichardW the terminology is *Pattern matching*, you can find more information here [is (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is)

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal> { new Cat(), new Cat(), new Dog(), new Cat(), new Dog() };

            var dogs = animals.OfType<Dog>().ToList();
            dogs.ForEach(dog => dog.Bark());

            var cats = animals.OfType<Cat>().ToList();
            cats.ForEach(cat => cat.Meow());

            var actualTypes = animals.Select(animal => animal.GetType()).ToList();
        }

        abstract class Animal { }

        class Dog : Animal { public void Bark() { } }

        class Cat : Animal { public void Meow() { } }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GetType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype?view=netframework-4.8) to get the type of the class.

```
List<Animal> lstA = new List<Animal>();
        lstA.Add(new Cat());
        lstA.Add(new Dog());
        foreach(Animal a in lstA)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type of {0}", a.GetType());
        }

abstract class Animal
{}
class Cat : Animal
{}
class Dog : Animal
{}
```